# Perl Scoping Array variable - for loop

Tags: arrays, perl, split

Im a newbie to Perl. My ask is to fill a array inside for loop and use the variable outside the loop.

```
foreach my $fp (glob("c/temp.txt"))
{
  open my $fh, "<", $fp or die "can't read open '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
  while (my $line = <$fh>)
  {
    chomp($line);
   my @array= split /[,\(\)]/, $line; 
  }
  close $fh or die "can't read close '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
 }
```

I need to use the values `@array` outside the foreach loop. Please suggest a way.

Comment: (1) The `glob` you show evaluates to _one_ item, that `c:/temp.txt` string. Perhaps you do it for simplicity but why not something more realistic, like `c:/*.txt` (2) When an `open` fails one normally looks at `$!` variable. If that `$OS_ERROR` is involved in some cooky overloading or such (and it incorporates `$!`) then so be it, but otherwise you should print `$!` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your array in the scope, where you need to use it. So, if you need it outside of the loop, declare it before the loop and it is available in the loop also. Like:

```
my @array;

foreach my $fp (glob("c/temp.txt"))
{
...
   @array= split /[,\(\)]/, $line; 
...
 }
```

Comment: And if they want to keep info about individual lines put references of `@array` on another array, `my @lines; for(...) { ... my @ary = split ...; push @lines, \@ary }`